# Objective-C - Get Selected Object from NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship in Core Data, and am having a good amount of trouble doing so - although I'm fairly new at Objective-C. I have two entities that I would like to tie together: Playlists and Songs. Each playlist will have a variety of songs, but each song can also be on several playlists, hence the many-to-many. After some looking around, I found that it may be easiest to do this by implementing a third entity which is essentially the "relationship" between the two. The Playlists would have a one-to-many relationship with the third entity, as would the Songs.. The reason for this would be so I could create / remove that third "relationship" entity when I want to add / remove a song from a playlist, and is better overall for organizing, at least in my opinion.

Last thing to note is that I have three basic tables in my window: A table that lists every playlist, a table that lists every song, and then a table that lists all the songs under whatever playlist is selected in the first table.

I'm currently stuck on how to create the "relationship" third entity based on the objects that are selected in both the playlists and songs arrays/tables. I understand how to create the entity, but don't know how I can call the array controller to give me the selected object. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance,

Pat

Comment: This Apple document appears to have some good explanations https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: Did you somehow miss the `selectedObjects` property of NSArrayController?

Comment: I'm aware of that code now, but since I've been learning objective-c primarily from any tutorials or examples I can find, I haven't found a way to implement it. How would I go from calling the selectedObjects of my NSArrayController to setting those values of my third entity? Thanks a lot for the help!